# Creating a popup from inside the Item Command event

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

is there a way I can create a popup or dialog window from inside a gridview's ItemCommand event?

What I am trying to do is if the transaction failed, I want to show the error message in a popup when they click the image button.

This is as far as I have gotten. Also how can I put the error message into the dialog? Should I save the message to the grid view in a hidden column? I'm not sure how to pass that value into the dialog box.

the ascx

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="TransactionListGrid" CssClass="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
            AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Growll" Width="700px" OnNeedDataSource="TransactionListGrid_NeedDataSource"
            ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" CellSpacing="0" OnItemDatabound="TransactionListGrid_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="TransactionListGrid_ItemCommand">
            <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
            </ClientSettings>
            <PagerStyle Position="Top" />
            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id,Amount,IsCredit,IsCancelled" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
                <NoRecordsTemplate>
                    <div>
                        No transactions found.</div>
                </NoRecordsTemplate>
                <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Order ID" DataField="Order_Id" />
                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn HeaderText="Credit" DataField="IsCredit" />
                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn HeaderText="Cancelled" DataField="IsCancelled" />
                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn HeaderText="Failed" DataField="IsFailed"  UniqueName="FailedCheckBox"/>
                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn HeaderText="Error" UniqueName="ErrorMessageButton" ButtonType="ImageButton"/>
                    <telerik:GridNumericColumn HeaderText="Amount" DataField="Amount" DecimalDigits="2" DataFormatString="{0:$######0.00}" />
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Last Four" DataField="CardLastFour" />
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

c#

```
 protected void TransactionListGrid_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ErrorMessage")
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest way is probably using AJAX. Put a `RadToolTip` on your page and ajaxify the tooltip and grid using the `RadAjaxManager` (or `RadAjaxPanel`). With the tooltip and grid ajaxified, you can just call the `RadToolTip.Show()` method in the `ItemCommand` event of the grid.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What would I set the TargetControlID to? And if I had the error message inside a hidden column how could it show inside the tooltip?

Comment: You would do it programmatically in the code-behind, probably during the `ItemDataBound` event. You may actually want to use the `RadToolTipManager` instead now that I think of it. I will update my answer when I have a minute.